# Why plt.savefig reduced the original size of an image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a following problem. I want to load an image and plot over it. Everything works fine, but when I save the final plot it seems to be reduced in size and quality. Do you know why? I need the newimage.png to be also 1026 x 824px and with the same quality as original img.png.

```
img = Image.open("./Python/img/img.png") #SIZE 1026 x 824px


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(img, extent=[0, 1024, 0, 768])

x = [10, 300, 100, 400]
y = [100, 250, 450, 600]



plt.xlim(0, 1024)
plt.ylim(0, 768)

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=100, alpha=1)

ax.invert_yaxis()

ax.imshow(img)

ax.xaxis.tick_top()

plt.savefig("./Python/img/newimage.png") #SIZE 432 x 288px
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A matplotlib figure has a size in inches and a dpi.  The saved figure pixel size is these two numbers multiplied by each other.  It has nothing to do with the size of data plotted on the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html
You will see a parameter called quality that is a scalar from 1 to 95, being 95 the best quality. There is also another parameter called dpi that is the resolution in dots per inch. I personally recommend to set this value to around 300.

You can use this:

```
plt.savefig('your-file.png', dpi=300, quality=95)
```

And then if the quality is too large you could always use another program to scale it.

Comment: The quality parameter is relevant only for jpeg images and is ignored otherwise.